# Splitting Dataset into train and test tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have a csv [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HrxX7DGkV26-JodvxNUmSN964iUoUFdh/view?usp=share_link) (280 MB) which I load into tensorflow using the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

data = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset("flight_2018.csv",
                                             batch_size = 1000,
                                             label_name="Cancelled",
                                             num_epochs = 20,
                                             num_parallel_reads=2)
```

The `type` of this object is `tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.PrefetchDataset` .

So I wanted to know how I could split this dataset into training and testing dataset which is shuffled before splitting.

Comment: One option is to separate the CSV file into two CSVs, one for train and the other for test. This could be done without tensorflow.

Answer (score 0):

As the type of your data is `tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.PrefetchDataset` you can use the [take](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/data/FixedLengthRecordDataset#take) and [skip](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#skip) methods to split the data.

```
train_data=data.take(160)
test_data=data.skip(160)
```

Kindly refer to this [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/synandi/196b22e4625bbcf84dda7ae8f710bf74/74329114.ipynb). Thank you!